# Ability to choose direction type for google maps intent

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I am using google maps intent to get directions. The problem is that the directions come up with whatever the last type of directions I searched on the google maps app.

For example if i used google maps to get walking directions last, when i use my app the directions will automatically search walking directions.

I want to give the user the ability to choose their direction type.

Here is a code snippet:

```
String directions = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + myLocationString + "&daddr=" + officeLocationString;

                            // Create Google Maps intent from current location to  target location
                            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                    Uri.parse(directions));
                            intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
                            fcontext.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit: As of January 2013, the Google Directions API has updated and the results are now provided in JSON.  The URL format now looks something like this**:

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Chicago,IL&destination=Los+Angeles,CA&waypoints=Joplin,MO|Oklahoma+City,OK&sensor=false`

**More info is available [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/).**

---

Adding the `directionsmode` parameter to your URI should do what you're looking for.

From the [URL scheme docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/):

> directionsmode: Method of transportation. Can be set to: driving, transit, or walking.

So perhaps you could try something like:

```
String directions = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + myLocationString + "&daddr=" + officeLocationString + "&directionsmode=" + directionsMode;
```

Comment: Very good thank you. Ideally I want the user to be able to choose their mode of transportation however.

Comment: That should not be a problem.  Since directionsMode is a variable, just set it to whatever mode the user specifies.  For example you could have a menu consisting of 3 icons, and just update the value of directionsMode corresponding to the mode the user selects.

Comment: Wait a minute, the question refers to Android, however this accepted answer refers to documentation for iOS, the two are not the same.  Also, the answer is out of date, the URL scheme is now comgooglemaps://query

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware the documentation I referenced was referring to iOS.  The URL scheme mentioned in my answer was still perfectly valid, however, since the original poster is simply opening an intent to parse whatever text is at that URL.  The URL scheme that Google is now using in that document (comgooglemaps://) is iOS specific, however.  I have updated my response with the device agnostic URL scheme.

Comment: This option didn't seem to work for me, while @JohanShogun's answer to use dirflg did the trick!

Answer (score 4):

I was unable to get it working with the above "&directionsmode=", it was just ignored.I did some tinkering in the webbrowser with URLS from google maps, I found that the "&dirflg" worked much better, both in the browser and in the android OS.

Use with these values: r = transit, b = biking, d = driving, w = walking

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to make `maps.google.com` work, but you can use the alternative `www.google.com/maps/dir` API if you have `origin_place_id` and `destination_place_id` (you can get them form [autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/autocomplete))

```
path = "comgooglemapsurl://www.google.com/maps/dir/"
queryItems = [
               (name: "api", value: "1"),
               (name: "origin", value: fromPlace.text),
               (name: "origin_place_id", value: fromPlace.id),
               (name: "destination", value: toPlace.text),
               (name: "destination_place_id", value: toPlace.id),
               (name: "travelmode", value: "driving"),
    ]
```

You can find why the schema was replaced from `https` to `comgooglemapsurl` [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme#launch-the-google-maps-app-for-ios-from-a-google-maps-desktop-url)